# ionic 3 Document Viewer Plugin

Tags: cordova, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using [Document Viewer Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/)  to show pdf file in my ionic 3 app.
I placed a pdf file in **assets folder** and call the method as they mentioned in their documentation.

```
const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: 'My PDF'
};
this.document.viewDocument('assets/myFile.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)
```

but It won't show anything. I used another built in method of this plugin:
`this.document.canViewDocument(url, contentType, options, onPossible, onMissingApp, onImpossible, onError)` 
it throws the onError callback function and error says:
 **'Relative URIs are not supported.'** 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use File Plugin Native Ionic and use:

`this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets/files/myFile.pdf`